# print 0 when counting a list item that is not in list

Tags: python, html, css, list, count

I'm stuck on producing "Red: 0" if red is not entered from the user input list. If I enter say "blue green white black silver silver silver blue silver black silver white white silver white white yellow red red silver red" the output will be:
red: 3
blue: 2

Which I want it to do. If I take out the red's from that list the output is :

blue: 2....I would like it to be:

red: 0
blue: 2

```
colors = []
cars = input("Cars: ")
colors.append(cars)
if "red" in cars:
  for color in colors:
    print("red:", cars.count("red"))
if "blue" in cars: 
   print("blue:", cars.count("blue"))
```

Comment: use `collections.Counter` on the splitted list of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use the if and for clauses; they're not necessary and skipping them solves your problem:

```
colors = []
cars = input("Cars: ")
colors.append(cars)
print("red:", cars.count("red"))
print("blue:", cars.count("blue"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Working off your example code, all you need to do is remove the `if`s:

```
cars = input("Cars: ")
print("red:", cars.count("red"))
print("blue:", cars.count("blue"))
```

DEMO:

```
>>> Cars: blue green white black silver silver silver blue silver black silver white white silver white white yellow red red silver red
red: 3
blue: 2

>>> Cars: blue green white black silver silver silver blue silver black silver white white silver white white yellow
red: 0
blue: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the split method to create a list from your input string.
Then to print the red result also you need to remove the if statement, so your final code would be something like this:

```
colors = []
cars = input("Cars: ")
colors = cars.split()
print("red:", colors.count("red"))
print("blue:", colors.count("blue"))
```

Comment: Great! Works well! Now my problem is if the word red is in a word such as "redish" it does not count it.....

Comment: To do what you're asking for a would define a new function that counts what you need.

`def counts(list, color):
      n = 0
      for item in list: 
           if color in item: 
                 n = n + 1
      return n`

And then your print would be (same for blue):

`print("red:", counts(colors, "red")`

Comment: I'm sorry if the comment format is a bit confusing but I'm new hear and I don't know that good how this works. (Be careful of indentation)